# What portion of Sura al-Hashr should minimally be recited as post salat and dua supplication?

Tags: practical-islam, sunnah, dua, quran-recitation, surat-al-hashr

I am Sunni hannafi muslim and the tradition at the masjids I attend, the imam recites the last portion of ayas from sura al-Hashr (Quran:59) after the duas of the morning (Fajr) and noon (Zuhr) salats, thus completing these ibada.  I am trying to memorize these ayas.  I would like to learn and recite the entire sura and InshAllah I will, but for the time being I would like to know which aya to start from and go to the end.  I believe it is from 59:21 to 59.24.  Or should I start earlier from 59:18?

Comment: I wonder if this doesn't fall into cultural issues (off-topic), as there's no -to me known- backup for this practice. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Narrated Ma'qil bin Yasar:
that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Whoever says three times when he gets up in the morning: 'A'udhu Billahis-Sami Al-'Alim Min Ash-Shaitanir-Rajim' and he recites three Ayat from the end of Surah Al-Hashr - Allah appoints seventy-thousand angels who say Salat upon him until the evening. If he dies on that day, he dies a martyr, and whoever reaches the evening, he holds the same status."(Tirmidhi)

Comment: @Faqirah Ok, I will do that every morning InshAllah. Thank you. You can post as answer and I will accept and up-vote